# Exercise 32 - Artur O. Lopes - Ordinary Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

prove that

$\text{det} \ e^{tA} = e^{t \ \text{tr}A}$ , for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and any matrix $A \in M(n)$.

**I'm trying to use Jordan's canonical form, but to no avail.**

Comment: It follows immediately from the JCF,  what was the problem?

Comment: If $A=P^{-1}JP$ then $e^{tA}=P^{-1}e^{tJ}P$. If $J$ is the Jordan canonical form of $A$, then along the diagonal of $e^{tJ}$ one has the terms $e^{t\lambda}$'s where $\lambda$'s ae the eigenvalues of $A$ (including multiplicity).